# Issues with configuration of Bitbucket Server with HTTPS reverse proxy using Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, bitbucket, tomcat8, bitbucket-server

I'm trying to install some Atlassian products (Bitbucket Server, Jira, Confluence etc.) on my VPS with using HTTPS. Every product should be available on their own subdomain e.g. `https://bitbucket.mydomain.de` or `https://jira.mydomain.de` I tried many things but now I'm very confused. It always redirect me to the Tomcat-GUI instead of my installed Bitbucket Server application. Maybe managing the ports is too confusing for me.

Three configuration files are involved - Tomcats `server.xml`, Apaches `mydomain.conf` file and Bitbuckets `bitbucket.properties` configuration.

I've tried to use an own Bitbucket Connector in Tomcat, while using an reverse Proxy in Apache. Here are some of my files.

Apaches `mydomain.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName bitbucket.mydomain.de
    ServerAlias bitbucket.mydomain.de

    ProxyRequests Off

    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://bitbucket.mydomain.de:7990/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://bitbucket.mydomain.de:7990/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain_ssl_certificate.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/mydomainprivate_key.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain_ssl_certificate_intermediate.cer
</VirtualHost>
```

Bitbuckets `bitbucket.properties`

```
server.port=7990
server.secure=true
server.scheme=https
server.proxy-port=443
server.proxy-name=bitbucket.mydomain.de
```

And Tomcats `server.xml`

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <...>
    <Service name="Catalina">
        <!-- Default Connector -->
        <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"/>

        <!-- Bitbucket Connector -->
        <Connector port="7990" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="443" compression="on" compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,application/json,application/javascript,application/x-javascript"
            secure="true" scheme="https" proxyName="bitbucket.mydomain.de" proxyPort="443" />

        <!-- SSL Connector -->
        <Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" enableLookups="false"
            disableUploadTimeout="true" acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keyAlias="tomcat"
            SSLEnabled="true" keystoreFile="keystore/mydomain-keystore.jks" keypass="mypass" keystoreType="JKS"/>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

Actually, it shows me on `bitbucket.mydomain.de` every single time the Tomcat GUI instead of Bitbucket.. and I can't explain why. What am I missing? I think the whole `server.xml` is misconfigured...

Thanks a lot for every help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something a little bit lighter than Apache like haproxy. Haproxy is available as a standard Linux package. Haproxy will terminate your SSL connection. It will act as a reverse proxy for the various Atlassian applications. See the following link for information on how to set it up:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/securing-bitbucket-server-behind-haproxy-using-ssl-779303273.html

You won't have to change your Tomcat server.xml

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm! It's much easier to use :) I heard never about it.